# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html, curl, php

Tags: php, curl, mime-types

I'm getting this error which i haven't seen before. I'm using cURL to try and get a captcha image from my site, but im getting this error instead of the image i want.

```
if(isset($_GET['captcha'])) {
 $curl->open("GET","https://mydomain.com");
 $curl->exec();

 preg_match('/_mobile_sess=[^;]+/', $curl->getHeaders(), $sess);
 $_SESSION['cookie'] = $sess[0]; 

 preg_match('/ame="authenticity_token" type=\"hidden\" value=\"(.+?)\"/i',$curl->responseText, $tkn);

 $_SESSION['token'] = $tkn[1];
 preg_match('/\/signup\/captcha\/([0-9-a-z]+)\.gif/i', $curl->responseText, $cs);
 $_SESSION['captchaUrl'] = $cs[1];

 $curl->open("GET", "http://mydomain.com" . $cs[0]);
 $curl->cookie = $_SESSION['cookie'];
 $curl->exec();
 echo $curl->responseText;

 die;
```

}

I've set the MIME type as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="image/gif">` in my head of my HTML doc but still get the same issue.

This is the form where i'm trying to output the image.

```
if(empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){
  echo "<center><form method='POST' action='?go'>
  <input  type='hidden' name='nameC' value='- SAFAL -' ><br/>
  <b>User Name</b><br><input name='login' size='30' id='login'    value='safal".rand(111111,9999999)."'><br/>
 <b>Password</b><br><input name='senha' id='senha' size='30' value='".rand()."'><br/>  <br>
 <img src='?captcha'><br/>
 <input name='cs' id='cs' placeholder='Put The Capcha' size='20'  onclick='if(this.value==\"Digite aqui\") this.value=\"\"'><br><br><br>
 <input type='submit' value='Click Here' id='btn'>
 </form>";
}
```

Comment: which error haven't you saw before ?

Answer (score 6):

Stumbled upon this question via Google Search. Adding my case for reference:

If you set a `background-image: url('../img/sample.png');` like this with single quotation marks, the Chrome/ Opera console will also show this warning.

Eliminating the quotation marks does the trick.

Comment: +1 - The same error can be seen with other malformed `background-image` declarations, such as `background-image: url();`. The malformed CSS can be anywhere on the page, or in a linked stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Put header('Content-Type: image/gif'); in your php block code before you are printing a stream to output.