# background image picture hosting

Tags: css, image

Trying to pull in a background image but keep getting this error in the console

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html

image is a png

here is my image path

```
h1 {
  background-image: url("http://imgur.com/pGM46FY")
}
```

Comment: In order to get a useful answer, you're going to have to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: Please upload your code as well so we can give you a better answer Anyway here are some similar questions that may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221497/resource-interpreted-as-image-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-curl-ph http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184379/meteor-resource-interpreted-as-image-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the full image path with the `.png`

In your case it would be

```
h1 {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/pGM46FY.png")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your `background-image` url is not an image, but a webpage:

**This would be right:**

```
h1 {
  background-image: url("http://imgur.com/pGM46FY.png")
}
```

Image urls will usually end in `.png`, `.jpg`, `.gif`

Answer (score 0):

Your image path is most likely set incorrectly, e.g. relative to the current directory "pics/myimage.png" vs. relative to the web root "/pics/myimage.png".

Answer (score 0):

MIME type of an object matters a lot while sending the data. This helps the server or the software to detect what type of file is being sent.

So, this message means, that the object (your image) was interpreted as an Image. But was sent down as a plain text HTML page.

MIME type has been changed to: `text/html`